# CPLEX time until first feasible solution

Tags: c++, cplex

I'm a beginner in CPLEX and C++ programming, and I'm trying to solve a medium size MIP problem.

My issue is that I need to know how much time CPLEX took to get the first feasible solution and to get the best feasible solution (not necessary the global optima).

I already know how to configure a time limit and I've been using the Solution Pool of CPLEX to get all the feasible solutions, but not its times.

Is there a direct code in CPLEX to get the time values for each feasible solution obtained?

Thanks

EDIT1: the code for the problem would be the following:

```
IloEnv env;
IloModel model(env);
IloCplex cplex(model);
IloCplex::Param::TimeLimit;

IloExpr term2(env);
IloExpr term3(env);
IloExpr objetivo(env);

IloInt i,j;
double CP;

IloNumVarArray z(env, columnas-1, 0, INFTY,ILOBOOL);
IloNumVarArray a(env, columnas, -1*INFTY, INFTY, ILOFLOAT);

for (i = 0; i < filas; i++){
    IloExpr term1(env);
    for(j = 0; j < columnas-1; j++){

        term1 += a[j]*(A[i+1][j+2]);
    }
    term2 += ((b[i+1])-(term1+a[columnas-1]))*((b[i+1])-(term1+a[columnas-1]));
    term1.end();
}

for(j = 0; j < columnas-1; j++){
        term3 += z[j];
    }
objetivo=term2/(sigmasq)+2*(term3+1)-(filas);

model.add(IloMinimize(env, objetivo));


for (j = 0; j < columnas-1; j++) {
    IloExpr restr(env);
    restr = a[j] + (bigM)*z[j];
    model.add(0 <= restr <= IloInfinity);
    restr.end();
}
for (j = 0; j < columnas-1; j++) {
    IloExpr restr(env);
    restr = (bigM)*z[j] - a[j];
    model.add(0 <= restr <= IloInfinity);
    restr.end();
}

cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::ClockType, 2);
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::TimeLimit, 3600);   

cplex.solve();
```

PD: Sorry that some parameters are in spanish, but that's my native language.

Comment: Can you provide code for what you've tried and where specifically you are getting hung up?

Comment: Sure, it's edited!

Comment: I'm actually not hunged up somewhere in the code, I just don't know what I can do to obtain those time values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [incumbent callback](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex_IncumbentCallbackI.html?cp=SSSA5P_12.6.3%2F2-9-8-0-25) to get the time (see the `getCplexTime` function) for every integer feasible solution found along the way (and including the final solution).  To get started, check out the `ilomipex4.cpp` example that is shipped with CPLEX for an example of how to use callbacks in general.  Also, see the [documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/progr_adv/callbacks_basic/18_Concert_title_synopsis.html) for implementing callbacks with Concert.

Comment: Thank you very much! that solves my problem perfectly!